# How can I write the natural numbers less than $n$ that are coprime to $n$?

Tags: list-manipulation, number-theory

How can I write the natural numbers less than $n$ that are coprime to $n$?

[image]

Comment: Please, post code, not images. After you do this you can read and format your code properly

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour]**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Answer (score 6):

This should be faster than existing answers:

```
With[{r = Range[#]}, Pick[r, CoprimeQ[r, #]]] &[10^7]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) to choose the correct elements out of a [`Range`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Range.html).

```
n = 10;
Select[Range[n], GCD[#, n] == 1 &]

(*--> {1, 3, 7, 9}*)
```

The functionalized form `GCD[#, n] == 1 &` is a pure [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) and returns either `True` or `False` when applied as e.g. `GCD[#, n] == 1 &[4]`.

The above is the 'ideal' Mathematica way, but it might not scale particularly well as you need to write down the entire list of numbers first. Your intuition is correct that you can go through the range up to `n` and only keep the numbers you want, and this is done using [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) as follows.

```
Reap[
 Do[
  If[GCD[i, n] == 1, Sow[i]]
  , {i, n}]
 ]
(*--> {Null, {{1, 3, 7, 9}}}*)
```

The output from `Reap` is the output from the `Do` (which is `Null`) and a list of all the `Sow`ed items of the different tags in use. This is faster than the above but only slightly so.

Comment: I did some quick-and-dirty timing, and it seems to me that the `Do` loop solution is faster for smaller ranges, but becomes slower for very large ranges (e.g. `n = 10000000`). Do you see the same?

Comment: @Marco One should really use David's approach. If there's an inbuilt function it will likely work better. I mentioned the Reap/Sow pair to formalize what the OP was trying to do but I don't think it's a great idea.

Answer (score 4):

Slight improvement over epistanty's first answer:

```
n = 10;
Select[Range[n], CoprimeQ[#, n] &]
```

It scales better than his first solution as well:

```
Timing[Select[Range[10^7], CoprimeQ[#, 10^7] &];]
```

{18.4778, Null}

```
Timing[Select[Range[10^7], GCD[#, 10^7] == 1 &];]
```

{23.3811, Null}

Answer (score 2):

For large values of `n` you could use `Compile`.

```
CoprimeList[n_] := CoprimeListcompiled[n, FactorInteger[n][[All, 1]]]

CoprimeListcompiled = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {ps, _Integer, 1}},
  Module[{S = Range[n]},
    Do[
      S[[k*i]] = 0,
      {k, ps}, {i, 1, n/k}
    ];
    Select[S, Positive]
  ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
];

CoprimeList[10^8] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {2.05012, 40000000}
> ```

```
EulerPhi[10^8]
```

> ```
> 40000000
> ```