# What is the shortest way to calculate Euler's Phi function ( excluding EulerPhi )?

Tags: programming, number-theory

With the risk of closure by the duplicate zombies ( this one might do: [How can I write the natural numbers less than $n$ that are coprime to $n$?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94215/how-can-i-write-the-natural-numbers-less-than-n-that-are-coprime-to-n/94267#94267) ) I dare to ask the following question.

My hobby project is the development of an interactive Elementary Number Theory Course ( tutorial ) written in Mathematica Wolfram Language.

Now, assume that Mathematica did not have EulerPhi as a native Function then what would be the shortest ( in characters ) way to calculate EulerPhi ?

To start with I have the following two examples:

```
53: s[n_] := Length[Select[Range[n], GCD[#, n] == 1 &]]

36: s[n_] := Sum[Floor[1/GCD[k, n]], {k, 1, n}]
```

What is the shortest way??

Comment: `DirichletConvolve[n, MoebiusMu[n], n, m]`?

Comment: I don't understand the m. EulerPhi is a function of n.

Comment: It's 40 characters anyway.

Comment: Not really a golfer, sorry; anyway: `Count[CoprimeQ[n, Range[n]], True]` (or `Range @ n ~CoprimeQ~ n ~Count~ True` in the Wizard-ian style), or `Total @ Boole @ CoprimeQ[n, Range[n]]`.

Comment: A beautiful solution, indeed !

Comment: 34 Characters, shortest so far :-) Including the s[n_]:= it's 42 I believe. Doesn't matter.

Comment: Maybe `Range@n~GCD~n~Count~1`

Comment: Avoid `Range[n]` with `n*Times @@ (1 - 1/FactorInteger[n][[All, 1]])` or `n*MoebiusMu@#.(1/#) &[Divisors@n]`

Comment: Small `LeafCount`: `Exponent[Cyclotomic[n, x], x]`