# Selecting elements in a list by a test on its image over a map

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I want to select all elements `x` in a list, which i'll name `List`  such that `GCD[x,n]=1`, for a given `n`. I've tried this:
`Select[Z[15], GCD[#, 15] = 1]`
And it's returning 
`Set::write: Tag GCD in GCD[15,#1] is Protected.`

Comment: Related [94215](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94215/45431) and especially this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94267/45431) if speed is important.

Comment: Maybe `Range[15] // Pick[#, GCD[#, 15], 1] &`

Comment: Never *ever* *ever* name a list `List`.  Not EVER!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, why?

Comment: `List` is a *Mathematica* function.  Calling a list `List` is about as confused as calling a general variable `Pi` or calling a register `Do` or calling a variable `Save` or a mathematical subroutine `Compile` or calling a matrix  `Equals` or an output file `Map`... In fact, you should never start the name of a variable, list, etc. with an upper-case letter, as it may conflict with the many system names in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Luckily, it won't let you define `List` to be anything because that symbol is protected in *Mathematica* since it's a built-in function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use `SameQ` (`===`) not `Set` (`=`), as well as invoke the ampersand so your anonymous function in the select fires:

`Select[Z[15], GCD[#, 15] === 1&]`

---

Due to OP's comment I'm going to spend a second talking about pure functions.

Let's say `Z[15]` really just meant `Range[15]`.  I don't know what OP means by $Z(n)$ but assuming OP meant positive integers, $0<z \leq 15$, gives us a list to work with.

One way to work with `Select` is to hand it a named discriminatory (returning `True`/`False`) function that take one and only one argument.  For example, something that takes a number $x$ and checks if its GCD with 15 is 1:

```
myGcd15isOneQ[x_] := GCD[x, 15] === 1
```

Armed with a predefined function we can go forth and conquer:

```
Select[Range[15], myGcd15isOneQ]
```

> {1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14}

Often with `Select` statements,  discriminatory functions are going to only be used in the context of one and only one particular `Select` statement.  Rather than invoke the overhead of defining a new global function that will only ever be called within a different function, we can carry out the entire deal by invoking a pure (anonymous) function solely within the context of the select.

```
Select[Range[15], GCD[#, 15] === 1 &]
```

> {1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14}

The only difference is we used `#` instead of the named variable `x` of the prior example, and we invoked an ampersand to fire the replacement of `#` with the values it was being mapped over.   Simply put, the ampersand grammatically defines the end of a pure function.  Can read more [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithPureFunctions.html).

Comment: Why the `&` sign?

Comment: This is a great question André.  This is something that gets a lot of people both with `Map` and `Select`.  I'll update my answer to elaborate.

Comment: The OP might also appreciate `Divisible[]` and `CoprimeQ[]`.